# Select box displaying duplicated results - How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript.

This query returns the correct results, I can see them in the console log.

But when displayed in the html select box, the first result seems repeated and the others are not displayed.

Is there something missing that cycles through all results before displaying them?

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
            var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

            var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
            query.include('toUser');
            query.include('SentTo');
            query.include("myBadge");
            query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
            query.equalTo("status", "Connected");

            query.find({
                                success: function (results) {
                                    var friends = [];
                                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                        friends.push({
                                            username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                                          //  userId: results[i].get('toUser').id


                                        });
                                        var select = document.getElementById("selectFriend");
                                        $.each(friends[0], function (i, v) {

                                            var opt = v;
                                            var el = document.createElement("option");
                                            el.textContent = opt;
                                            el.value = opt;
                                            select.appendChild(el);
                                        })

                                    }
                                },
```

---

Results are displayed via

```
                        ![<select id="selectFriend">
                            <option>Select friend to send to</option>
                        </select>][1]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MarcellFülöp - Question edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only iterating through the first object in `friends` array.

```
$.each(friends[0], function (i, v) {
     var opt = v;
     var el = document.createElement("option");
     el.textContent = opt;
     el.value = opt;
     select.appendChild(el);
})
```

Should be something like

```
$.each(friends, function (i, v) {
      var opt = v.username;
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code with your original code,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezvnp/124/)

```
 var optionExists = ($('#selectNumber option[value=' + v.username + ']').length > 0);
 if(!optionExists){
        select.appendChild(el);
  }
```